# create special chain property using protege

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology, protege

Suppose I have `class:music`, `class:musicStyle` and `class:Singer`.
`property:music_Has_Style`, `property:singer_sing_music`.

Suppose I want define `class:expert_Style` with subClasses:`Roc_expert, Pop_expert and Jazz_expert` such that every singer that sing at least 5 music in a style, for example Pop, is expert of that style.

How Can I add this restrain in subClasses:`Roc_expert, Pop_expert and Jazz_expert` ?

For example sth like this:

`Pop_expert is equivalent to: singer singer_sing_music min 5 (music music_has_style Pop)`

Comment: You want to have the last shown example in OWL syntax?

Comment: yes, I want to add it using protege, in `equivalent to` part for classes

Comment: Bye the way, I would stick to a naming convention, especially when to use upper resp. lower case character - at least from your examples it's a mix of several styles.

Comment: Ok, but what you've shown is more or less what you need to write in the editor:`Singer singer_sing_music min 5 (music music_Has_Style some Pop)` Do you get any error or what doesn't work?

Comment: It's ok but I create `Pop` as instance of `musicStyle`. your answer is for when `Pop` is subClass of `musicStyle`. How can handle this ?

Comment: I changed it such that `singer_sing_music min 5 (music music_Has_Style value Pop)`. I thing it's correct

Comment: @soheil rather than adding all these comments, you should really [edit] your question to add the necessary details. It will make it easier to read and understand what your problem is.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that there is an instance `Pop`, and yes, then **value** is correct in the Protege editor (which basically supports simplified Manchester OWL Syntax).

Comment: In part `equivalent To` I exactly wrote `singer_sing_music min 5 (music_Has_Style value Pop)`, and one of my instances sing 5 music in pop, but reasoner didn't recognize it as `Pop_expert` !!!